# How to use org.openimaj.ml.gmm to construct speaker models.

Tags: verification, speaker, openimaj

I would like to know how I can get GMM speaker model using OpenIMaj library. 
org.openimaj.ml.gmm.GaussianMixtureModelEM. I have tried following

```
GaussianMixtureModelEM gmm = new GaussianMixtureModelEM
         (DEFAULT_NUMBER_COMPONENTS,GaussianMixtureModelEM.CovarianceType.Diagonal);

MixtureOfGaussians mixture =  gmm.estimate(data);
boolean convergerd  = gmm.hasConverged();
```

I get **true** that GaussianMixtureModelEM has converged, I am lost where to go from here. Any help guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you're hoping to achieve? Once you've performed GMMEM, you would typically use the resultant MixtureOfGaussian model to compute probabilities or draw samples.

Comment: I have 935 points each with dimension 20, I used 256 components. gmm.estimate(data) returns me 256 guassians and 256 weight vectors where each Gaussian has mean and variance (both with dimension 20), next as you mentioned I can compute probabilities or I can draw samples from Gaussian distribution . How I can get single logLikelyhood value ? should I compute probability for a given points in space relative to the PDF represented by the gaussian mixture and sum them up ?

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, then `mixture.estimateLogProbability(point)` should do what you want (see http://www.openimaj.org/apidocs/org/openimaj/math/statistics/distribution/MixtureOfGaussians.html#estimateLogProbability(double[])).

Comment: Thankyou Jon, I figured it out. Jon if I am not mistaking you are one of the authors of Openimaj. I have been looking for the source of GMM and others related if you could kindly direct me where I cant get source.

Comment: Hi, is it safe to convert double log[] prob = mixture.estimateLogProbability(point) to get actual probability by taking exponential of logProb.

Comment: Code is here: https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/master/machine-learning/clustering/src/main/java/org/openimaj/ml/gmm/GaussianMixtureModelEM.java

Yes, to estimate actual probability it's safe to use the exponential.

Comment: So far so good. Classical Gaussian mixtures worked great. Any advice how to extend GMM-EM to GMM-EM MAP training? So that it can also be used for universal background modeling?